# Checking if a number has any repeated elements

Tags: python, math, split, integer

I have been working on spliting integers into the digits they are comprised of and then checking whether there are any repeated numbers in the list. However the code seems to always say there are no repeated numbers, even if there are.

My Code:

```
def repeatCheck(myList, repeatedNumber):
    seen = set()
    for number in myList:
        if number in seen:
            repeatedNumber = True
        seen.add(number)
    return repeatedNumber


def numberWorks(number, finalNumber):    
    digits = [int(n) for n in str(number)]
    repeatedNumber = False
    repeatCheck(digits, repeatedNumber)
    if repeatedNumber == False:
        print(number, "succeeded repeatedNumber")
        found = True
    else:
        print(number, "failed repeatedNumber")
        pass
    return number


number = 1000000000

while found == False:
    numberWorks(number, finalNumber)
    number += 1
print(finalNumber)
```

With input number 1000000000, the output should be 1023456789

Please let me know of anything that could be done to solve it, or if the code I have given is not enough.

Thank you.

Comment: Could you explain the significance of `conitionedNumber`. Additionally, your use of scope is all over the place, that code wont even run because of the indent at the bottom. You should probably work on figuring out how return statements work.

Comment: Please add example input and expected output

Comment: BTW, reading what you have written as the title, there are many ways to solve this, but first give us an example.

Comment: You need `==` instead of `=` in the last while loop and you are missing `:` after it.

Comment: To test your function, I suggest comparing the output of your function with the boolean value `len(set(str(number))) == len(str(number))`, which is a (cheating) way to check that there are no duplicate digits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call the function `repeatCheck()` you don't pass a reference to the variable `repeatedNumber`, so any changes to the variable do not affect the original definition of `repeatedNumber`. Therefore, the `repeatedNumber` defined in `numberWorks()` is never updated.

what you could do instead is assign the `return` value of `repeatCheck` to `repeatedNumber`.

```
repeatedNumber = False
repeatedNumber = repeatCheck(digits)
```

and rewrite `repeatCheck` to return `True` or `False` upon seeing a repeat:

```
def repeatCheck(myList):
    seen = set()
    for number in myList:
        if number in seen:
            return True
        seen.add(number)
    return False
```

This way you circumvent the ambiguity of reusing the variable name `repeatedNumber`

Comment: Thank you! I edited the code you gave a bit into one line

```
if repeatCheck(digits) == False:
```
and changed the function to how you had done it.

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to check for repeated digits inside a number here's a quick way to do it that returns a boolean.

```py
def noRepeatedDigits(number:int) -> bool:
  return all([str(number).count(i) == 1 for i in set(str(number))])

print(noRepeatedDigits(12344))
print(noRepeatedDigits(1234))
```

```
False #indicates it failed the check
True #indicates it passed the check
```

Answer (score 1):

I would simply delete all your code and do this.

```
def repeatCheck(repeatedNumber):
    numbersdub = list(str(repeatedNumber))
    numbers = set(numbersdub)
    for num in numbers:
        numbersdub.remove(num)
    return set(numbersdub)


print(repeatCheck(78788))
```

This will give you a set of all dubbels.

Comment: The complexity of `.remove` is linear, which means that the overall complexity of this function is quadratic.

Comment: You could get the set of all duplicates with linear time complexity using `collections.Counter` instead of `list`. `collections.Counter` is ideal for multisets. Thus `s = str(repeatedNumber); return (collections.Counter(s) - collections.Counter(set(s))).keys()` would be linear and return the duplicates.

Comment: Of course in base 10 there are only 10 possible different digits, so you can mostly ignore my previous comments :)

Comment: You solution is O(n * m) where n is the number of digits of the number, and m is the number of distinct digits of the number. In that sense it's quadratic. But m <= min(n, b) where b is the base (10 in decimal). If b is considered constant (such as 10) then your solution is linear. However, note that the OP is calling their function `repeatCheck` in a **huge** loop (they're iterating over 10**10 numbers), so every optimization we can have is important, and the only way to know which solution is best is using `timeit`.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative one-line solution:

```py
finalNumber = next(n for n in range(1000000000, 2000000000) if len(set(s := str(n))) == len(s))

print(finalNumber)
# 1023456789
```

**Explanation:** `len(str(n))` is the number of digits of `n`, whereas `len(set(str(n)))` is the number of unique digits of `n`. These two quantities are equal if an only if `n` doesn't have repeated digits.

The whole thing is wrapped in an iterator, and `next( )` returns the first value of the iterator.